# How do I print Django form data from views.py?

Tags: python, django

So I have a form running on Django and I'm trying to print the form.cleaned_data from views.py but it does not print anything in the shell.

```
$ views.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)


        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            print(form.cleaned_data)

            # redirect to a new URL:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/thanks/')


    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

The fix is probably very easy I'm just a newbie at Django.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have made a small typo mistake

```
cleaned_data
```

the d in cleanded_data is in small case

Comment: Fixed but it still doesnt print anything

Comment: make sure to put something in the form ;_)

Comment: Yes I go to the form, I enter in my name and click submit it redirects me to thanks.html but does not print the form data

Comment: sorry but i cant find any other problem in that

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by printing it in def thanks(Request) instead of in the POST section